# Python will not pull values from dictionary properly using for loop

Tags: python

Im trying to use a dictionary to check a given number of servers listed for a particular SQL backup success or fail. My problem so far is when I run this code:

```
for serverChk in srvrDict['Server']:
```

it returns the server name as single characters on each new line like:
S
E
R
V
E
R
So in my trial I see this "Error connecting to **T** to check OS version" where T is the fist character of the servername. I can't seem to put my finger on it and all the searching I've done has lead me to asking. 
Thanks!

```
class checkstatus:
#def getServers(self):
    chkbkpstats = csv.reader(file('c://temp//networkerservers.csv'))
    for row in chkbkpstats:
        srvrDict = {}
        srvrDict['Server'] = row[0]
        srvrDict['Instance'] = row[1]
        print srvrDict

for serverChk in srvrDict['Server']:
        try:
            c = wmi.WMI(server)
            for os in c.Win32_OperatingSystem():
                osVer = os.caption
        except:                 
            print 'Error connecting to %s to check OS version' % serverChk

        if '2003' in osVer:
            print 'w2k3'
        if '2008' in osVer:
            print 'w2k8'
```

Comment: Could you please show what `srvrDict['Server']` is at the beginning of iteration? It looks like it's a single string and thus the iteration occurs over each character. If it's a delimited string of server names, you will need to split the list first.

Comment: what is the type of `srvrDict['Server']`, try `type(srvrDict['Server'])`, is it a dict or string?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure - {'Instance': 'P1RT04', 'Server': 'THP06ASU'}

Comment: Like I said in my answer your line `for serverChk in serverDict['Server']` translates to `for serverChk in 'THP06ASU'`. You should instead use `for instance,server in serverDict.iteritems()`. Now `server` is the value you will want to print out. Or if you just want the values then you can use `for server in serverDict.values()`

Comment: Wow, thanks everyone for the quick reply. Im on my way home but will check these out when I get logged back in. (Im new to Python and I thank everyone for your time and help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the `Server` and `Instance` values in `srvrDict` each iteration of your loop through `chkbkpstats`, not actually generating a sequence of data with an entry for each item in your log file as it appears you expect.  You need to make that a list containing dictionaries, which you append to each iteration.  You are probably looking for something more like:

```
chkbkpstats = csv.reader(file('c://temp//networkerservers.csv'))
srvrs = []
for for row in chkbkpstats:
    srvrs.append({'Name' : row[0], 'Instance' : row[1]})
for srvr in srvrs:
    try:
        c = wmi.WMI(srvr['Instance'])
    except:                 
        print 'Error connecting to %s to check OS version' % srvr['Name']
    else:
        osVer = c.Win32_OperatingSystem()[0].Caption
        if '2003' in osVer:
            print 'w2k3'
        elif '2008' in osVer:
            print 'w2k8'
```

Comment: This is working so far. When I do a print on srvrs I get a long this of stuff but it returns me the OS ver for each.

Comment: Printing `srvrs` is just going to dump the dict as a string.  Not really useful.  What else do you need to do with this data set?

Comment: after getting the OS version of Win (2k3, 2k8). I will use the results to check a file on the server to see if a backup has failed/inprogress/successful. There is a different location for this file between w2k3 and w2k8. That is why I needed the OS version

Comment: So rather then having the print 'w2k3' I would want it to check a dir for a file: c:\temp\instance.ok, c:\temp\instance.err, c:\temp\instance.log. If .ok success, if .err, failed, if .log still running.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense.  So is your question answered then?  :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have stored a string in your dictionary. So the line `for serverChk in srvrDict['Server']` translates to `for serverChk in yourSavedString`. This is why you are getting individual characters. To access individual dictionary items you should do `for k,v in srvrDict.iteritems()` where `k` is the key and `v` is the value.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code.

First, you create a new `srvrDict` each time you go through the first `for` loop, overwriting the value that was stored in this variable the last time. I think, what you actually intended to do is the following:

```
srvrDict = {}
for row in chkbkpstats:
    srvrDict[row[0]] = row[1]
```

Now, `srvrDict` will contain an entry like `{'P1RT04': ['THP06ASU']}` for each row in `chkbkpstats`, mapping server names to lists of instances running on that server.

Then, in the second loop, use `for serverChk in srvrDict:` to iterate over all the entries in the dictionary. However, I'm not sure where the variable `server` in `c = wmi.WMI(server)` comes from. If this is what has been `row[1]` in the first loop, then you should use `srcvDict[serverChk]` to retrieve the value from the dictionary.

This way, the whole procedure would look something like this:

```
chkbkpstats = csv.reader(file('c://temp//networkerservers.csv'))
srvrDict = {}
for row in chkbkpstats:
    name, instance = row[0], row[1]
    if name not in srvrDict:
        srvrDict[name] = []
    srvrDict[name].append(instance)

for server in srvrDict:
    for instance in srvrDict[server]:
        try:
            c = wmi.WMI(instance)
        except:                 
            print 'Error connecting to %s to check OS version' % server
        else:
            osVer = c.Win32_OperatingSystem()[0].caption
            if '2003' in osVer:
                print 'w2k3'
            elif '2008' in osVer:
                print 'w2k8'
            else:
                print 'unknown OS'
```

PS.: I'm not sure what's the return value of `c.Win32_OperatingSystem()`. [...] **Update:** Thanks to sr2222 for pointing this out. Code fixed.

Update: Edited the code to allow for one server hosting multiple instances.

Comment: According to the WMI tutorial, all calls to the various interfaces return lists.  In the case of `Win32_OperatingSystem`, the list will always have 1 element.

Comment: Should really try to pare down the code in the `try:` block, especially with a catchall `except:`.

Comment: @sr2222 You are absolutely right, but then again, my code would look 90% like yours, except that I'm using a single dictionary... :-/

Comment: Meh, wouldn't offend me.  I'd rather SO be a good reference no matter which answer they read than have something be less than it could be for fear of looking plagiarized.

Comment: @tobias_k I adjusted my code to reflect your modifications and I ended up with cascading odd results. I'd try and post but it will not fit correctly in this box. What I am looking for is 1 dictionary per server and instance. The number of servers/instances I have vary from day to day. From there I want to check the OS version of Win (2k3, 2k8). I will use the results to check a file on the server to see if a backup has failed/inprogress/successful.

Comment: @DaryleB Can you provide a sample of a few lines from your log file you are parsing in your question?  It's hard to tell what's wrong when we don't know where we start.

Comment: @DaryleB If you want to have one dict per server, you should employ sr2222's solution. Mine uses a single dictionary, containing the individual server names and instances as key-value pairs. Also, could you please explain "cascading odd results"?

Comment: @sr2222 - I am using a csv file that contains 'servername, instance'. Some servers can have more then 1 instance running on them and someday I'd like to have 1 server name with multiple instance entry's but thats not for right now.

Comment: @tobias_k Here is a snipit
{'THP06ASU': 'P1RT04'}  
{'THP06ASU': 'P1RT07'}  
{'THP06ASU': 'P1RT01'}  {'THP06ASU': 'P1RT03'}  
{'THP70ASS': 'P1RT10', 'THP06ASU': 'P1RT03'}  
{'THP70ASS': 'P1RT10', 'THP06ASU': 'P1RT02'}  
{'THP04AST': 'P1RT08', 'THP70ASS': 'P1RT10', 'THP06ASU': 'P1RT02'}  
{'THP04AST': 'P1RT09', 'THP70ASS': 'P1RT10', 'THP06ASU': 'P1RT02'}  
{'THP04AST': 'P1RT09', 'THP70ASS': 'P1RT10', 'THP02ASR': 'P1RT02', 'THP06ASU': 'P1RT02'}  
{'THP04AST': 'P1RT09', 'THP70ASS': 'P1RT10', 'THP02ASR': 'P1RT04', 'THP06ASU': 'P1RT02'}

Comment: @tobias_k - thats the best I can get. The breaks are not showing but you can see whats going on between the {}. And there is more that just keeps coming in and the end result is this long string:
{'THP02ASR': 'P1RT06', 'THP70ASS': 'P1RT09', 'THP101SR': 'P1MI02', 'THP04AST': 'P1RT10', 'THP006SR': 'P1MI03', 'THP06ASU': 'P1RT02', 'THPNWSS5': 'P3EWS', 'THP36BSQ': 'P1RT01'}  and it doens't contain all server/instances I need

Comment: @DaryleB The problem is: "Some servers can have more then 1 instance running on them". In my solution I assumed that there is a 1:1 mapping of servers to instances. In this case, you should really try sr2222's solution, or you could use a dict {serverName: [list of instances]} if you like.

Comment: @tobias_k - I did try the dict {serverName: [list of instances]} and failed horribly. For now sr2222's solution works. When I get a better handle on working with python I will go bad and refine the process. 

Thanks everyone for the support :)